# How to erase the last n elements in the C++ map?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a nice and simple way to find `nth element` in `C++` `std::map`? Particularly I'm looking for an algorithm to erase the last `k` elements from the `map`. That would make sense to retrieve the iterator to the `nth element` and call `std::map::erase`. The requirement is that complexity doesn't suffer - that should be possible to erase the element range in `O(N)`.

Copy of the data shouldn't be made just to erase the elements. For example one solution is to copy the data into `std::vector`, then do `std::nth_element` on `std::vector`, and then `std::map::find` to find the iterator in order to find out where to erase from.

One of other solutions is to just iterate over `std::map` maintaining a counter variable on the number of elements to remove. That would give `O(n)`. Is that possible to replace the `for` loop with `STL algorithm`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maps don't provide better-than-linear access to elements by index, like `vector` or `deque`. You can do this using `std::advance`, but it takes time that is proportional to `k`. If `k` is small, it will often be fast enough - it basically involves following `k` pointers. Here's an example:

```
template<typename Map>
void erase_last_elements(Map & map, ptrdiff_t k)
{
    assert(k >= 0);
    assert(map.size() >= (size_t)k);
    typename Map::iterator i = map.end();
    std::advance(i, -k);
    map.erase(i, map.end());
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using Boost, you can use `boost::prior`:

```
template<typename Map>
void erase_last_elements(Map & map, ptrdiff_t k)
{
    assert(k >= 0);
    assert(map.size() >= (size_t)k);
    typename Map::iterator i = boost::prior(map.end(), k);
    map.erase(i, map.end());
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to maintain a separate index, or use a different container. Something like a sorted `vector` might be appropriate, if you don't insert and remove elements too much.

Comment: Is there any reason why `std::map` doesn't provide a `O(log(n))` solution to access the nth element?

Comment: It should be more efficient to remove "end() - 1" for k times.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable solution Stefan.

Comment: @Leonid - they don't have fast access to the Nth element because they'd have to maintain a separate index, which would require more memory, or slow down inserting or deleting.

Comment: @Stefan - why do you think it would be faster to do that? Asymptotically, the complexity is the same, and there are potentially fewer tree rebalances required if you remove them all in one erase call.

Comment: @Doug - right, that makes sense. You can get away with 4 bytes per node in a tree, but mostly it would be redundant, especially when  elements are similar in size to integers in a map.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Answer not applicable after edit of original post.

Comment: That is exactly what I would not like to do.